# Javascript - Array of item Objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
offers.makeOffer ({
        partnerSteamId: steam_id.toString(),
        accessToken: token.toString(),
        itemsFromMe: [
            {
                appid: 730,
                contextid: 2,
                amount: 1,
                assetid: checkedItems[i].id
            }
        ],
        itemsFromThem: []
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
      }
});
```

The `itemsFromMe` section contains the following:

```
itemsFromMe: [
     {
         appid: 730,
         contextid: 2,
         amount: 1,
         assetid: checkedItems[i].id
     }
]
```

However I need a way to built this based on `checkedItems.length` for example (Obviously this example won't work but it demonstrates my desired output):

```
offers.makeOffer ({
        partnerSteamId: steam_id.toString(),
        accessToken: token.toString(),
        itemsFromMe: [
            for (var i = 0; i < checkedItems.length: i++) {
               {
                    appid: 730,
                    contextid: 2,
                    amount: 1,
                    assetid: checkedItems[i].id
               }
            }
        ],
        itemsFromThem: []
      }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
      }
});
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You can make itemsFromMe a function that either executes once when the object is created, or can be executed whenever and return the latest checked items.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an immediately invoked function:

```
var o = {
    items: (function () {
        var a = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            a.push(i);
        }
        return a;
    }())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
itemsFromMe: (function() {
    return checkedItems.map(function(item) {
        return {
            appid: 730,
            contextid: 2,
            amount: 1,
            assetid: item.id
        }
    })
})()
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the syntax? getting the following error:
`})()
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Comment: @user3662307 -- Yeah, damn, one sec.

Comment: @user3662307 -- Fixed it.. missing `)` at the end of the `.map` function

Comment: This gives the following output:


`itemsFromMe: [
    appid=730, 
    contextid=2,
    amount=1, 
    assetid=3431655443
]`

But I need:


`itemsFromMe: [
    {
        appid=730, 
        contextid=2,
        amount=1, 
        assetid=3431655443
    {
]`